# How to execute another query in a running query after a specific number of records using php?

Tags: php, sql, database

I searched a lot but didn't found the exact result that I need. I have a project of question and blog website. There are two tables question_table and blog_table, now I want to execute both in two different queries and ORDER BY date on one page as newsfeed. I'm sorry if I didn't explain well.

Attached Image for detail description (result must like this)

[image]

My sql query `"SELECT * FROM blog_table WHERE status=1 ORDER BY posted_date DESC"`
and same for question_table
`"SELECT * FROM question_table WHERE status=1 ORDER BY posted_date DESC"`

Please help me to findout the exact result in the image bellow.

How can I run this query:

```
select posted_at,user_id,post_title,post_data from blog_table 
UNION 
select asked_at,user_id,question_title,question_slug from question_table 
order by date desc
```

Comment: Use `UNION` to combine the two queries. You'll have to select just the columns that are similar between the two tables, rather than `SELECT *`.

Comment: How i can run the query then `code`select posted_at,user_id,post_title,post_data from blog_table UNION select asked_at,user_id,question_title,question_slug from question_table order by date desc`code`

Answer (score 1):

Your `ORDER BY` only applies to the `question_table` query, not the whole thing. You need to put the `UNION` in a subquery so you can order the entire result.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    select posted_at AS date, user_id, post_title AS title, post_data AS content 
    from blog_table 
    UNION 
    select asked_at AS date, user_id, question_title AS title, question_slug AS content 
    from question_table
) AS x
order by date desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your try then how I can fetch the data as i always done `run = mysqli_query(connection,query);` and then `while row = mysqli_fetch_array(run)`?

Comment: Exactly like that.

Comment: It will have `$row['date'], $row['user_id'], $row['title'], $row['content']`

Comment: can you please explain `AS x` in short words? I'm receiving this error `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given `

Comment: SQL requires that when you select from a subquery you give it an alias. `AS x` is an arbitrary alias.

Comment: There are hundreds or thousands of questions about that error message. The answer is always to print the SQL error message to see what the error is in your query.